# Swift: How to wrap an async method in a synchronous method?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to load Javascript synchronously in my `WKWebView`. From my research it looks like the `evaluateJavaScript` method is asynchronous and this is causing errors because the page would load before the JS that overrides a lot of behavior (it only works a portion of the time because of the async nature).

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work  :

```
extension WKWebView {
  func evaluateJavaScriptSynchronously(script: String, completion: () -> Void) {
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1)

    evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) in
      if error == nil {
        if result != nil {
          print("SUCCESS")
          completion()
        }
      } else {
        print("ERROR!!!")
        print(error)
        print(result)
        completion()
      }
      dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }

    let timeout = dispatch_time_t(10000)
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, timeout)
  }
}
```

I know it's not working because the page still sometimes loads as if the JS wasn't there. Is there a similar thing I can do to synchronize the process?

Comment: I would suggest the ol' Kobayashi Maru: Redefine the problem. You are likely trying to solve the problem in the wrong way. Rethink your approach and try to work with the asynchronicity rather than against it. Blocking the current thread is rarely the best solution.

Comment: @InfinityJames but the callbacks that are made available through `WKNavigationDelegate` don't give me much freedom as to when i can call this method.

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correctly, but how about waiting until the web view completes loading, and then executes the JS?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen i have 2 snippets of javascript, one that needs to be completely loaded prior to the request, and one after. for the one before, i call `evaluateJavascript` in `func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)` but that doesn't seem to be finished sometimes by the time the request is done

Comment: Um, why do you want to run JS before the page is loaded (the page is empty at that point!)?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen i want to run JS that affects all elements e.g. `HTMLVideoElement.prototype.play = function() {}`. but this seems to not work after the page is refreshed. would there be a better way?

Comment: Oh I see, the problem here is that you need to run your javascript after HTML has finished loading, and before any other javascript in the page runs. It's pretty tricky, as iOS doesn't notify when that happens (and even if it does, and you run your javascript at that point, your script and the page's script will run in parallel).

Comment: If you own the page, it'd be easy, just inject your script in the <head> element, before other script. Otherwise, you'd have to load the HTML manually and inject your script in the <head> then pass the modified HTML back to the web view. I don't see another way :|

Comment: @KhanhNguyen looks like doing it in `didStartProvisionalNavigation` was the wrong place. when I ran it in `didCommitProvisionalNavigation` i think the request has already started so it works. i tried it with `setInterval(function() {console.log(HTMLVideoElement.prototype.play)}, 1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `WKNavigationDelegate` to get notified when the page into the `WKWebView` has been loaded

```
class Controller: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view = webView
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("page loaded")
        // <--- call your method from here
    }
}
```

You can now call your method from within `webView(wevView:didFinishNavigation:)`